# Excel Logical Function to Concatinate

Tags: excel, function, search, find, match

I'm trying to concatenate values based on the value of a cell, however, this requires a logical function. I've tried it with both FIND, MATCH and SEARCH, but it's not outputting the expected results.

How do I get it to work expectedly?

Suppose the expected result must be an email address generation where it is in the form of *firstname*@*company.com*, but you may have values which looks like "John Doe", "Sales", "John", etc.

This is the functions which I have used, without any success:

### MATCH

***Function***

`=IF(COUNTBLANK([@Name]) = 0; IF(MATCH(" "; [@Name]; -1) = 1; CONCATENATE([@Name]; "@company.com"); CONCATENATE(LEFT( [@Name]; FIND( " "; [@Name] ) - 1 ); "@company.com")); "")`

Note: Match parameters have been tested amongst -1, 0 and 1. -1 provides the best results.

***Result***

Where the lookup cell contains "John Doe", the concatenation result looks like *John Doe@company.com*, and "John" looks like *John@company.com*. This does not seem to work. When parameters for MATCH changes to 0 or 1, the result is *#N/A* on all.

### FIND

***Function***

`=IF(COUNTBLANK([@Name]) = 0; IF(FIND(" "; [@Name]) = 1; CONCATENATE([@Name]; "@company.com"); CONCATENATE(LEFT( [@Name]; FIND( " "; [@Name] ) - 1 ); "@company.com")); "")`

***Result***

Where the lookup cell contains "John Doe", the concatenation result looks like *John@company.com*, and "John" looks like "#VALUE!". This does not seem to work effectively.

### SEARCH

***Function***

`=IF(COUNTBLANK([@Name]) = 0; IF(SEARCH(" "; [@Name]) <= 1; CONCATENATE([@Name]; "@company.com"); CONCATENATE(LEFT( [@Name]; FIND( " "; [@Name] ) - 1 ); "@company.com")); "")`

***Result***

Where the lookup cell contains "John Doe", the concatenation result looks like *John@company.com*, and "John" looks like "#VALUE!". This does not seem to work effectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was possible to overcome this issue by using the FIND function, but changing the logical test to check for an error in the find results.

Where you look for a value which is not present, the FIND function will generate a "#VALUE!" error. Simply nest the FIND function into an ISERROR function without any =, < or >. This is the logical test for the FIND function.

`=IF(COUNTBLANK([@Name]) = 0; IF(ISERROR(FIND(" "; [@Name]));  CONCATENATE([@Name]; "@company.com");  CONCATENATE(LEFT( [@Name]; FIND( " "; [@Name] ) - 1 ); "@company.com")); "")`